# How do I find the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{2x+3}\sqrt{x+1}}{7-6x+4x^2}$

Tags: limits

I know how to find the limit of rational functions, but the numerator makes it hard for me to see where I should start when it comes to this function.Does anyone have some tips?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{2x+3}\sqrt{x+1}}{7-6x+4x^2}$$

Comment: As $x \to \infty$, $\dfrac{1}{x} \to 0$.

Comment: When $x$ is very large, the numerator is roughly $\sqrt2 x^2$. Can you use that?

Comment: Square the expression if you don‘t like the roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\begin{align}\frac{x\sqrt{2x+3}\sqrt{x+1}}{7-6x+4x^{2}}&=\frac{\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{2x+3}\sqrt{x+1}}{\frac{7}{x^{2}}-\frac{6}{x}+4}
\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{3}{x}}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{7}{x^{2}}-\frac{6}{x}+4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ohhh, I see! How smart! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is very simple with *asymptotic equivalents*: use that a polynomial is equivalent (at $\infty$) to its *leading term*, and equivalence is compatible with products and quotients.

*Some details*:

$\sqrt{2x+3}\sim_\infty \sqrt{2x}$, $\;\sqrt{x+1}\sim_\infty \sqrt x$, $\;7-6x+4x^2\sim_\infty 4x^2$, so
$$\frac{x\sqrt{2x+3}\sqrt{x+1}}{7-6x+4x^{2}}\sim_\infty\frac{x\sqrt{2x}{\sqrt x}}{4x^2}=\frac{\sqrt 2\, x^2}{4x^2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}4. $$